# Symfony & TimeType | input string not working?

Tags: symfony

following issue: If have got a field value in my entity, this field is a string.
I'm using a form in order to ask for the value. But I want a string time value. Therefore:

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if($data){
        $attr = array_merge(['data-type'=>$data->getProperty()->getType(), 'class' => 'property-destination'],$data->getProperty()->getParams()??[]);
        $form->add('value',$data->getProperty()->getFormType(),[
            'label' => 'Opens',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => true,
            'input' => 'string',
            'with_seconds' => false,
        ]);
    }
});
```

When asking $data->getProperty()->getFormType(), it returns a TimeType::class.
Using 'input' => 'string' it should return a string and not a DateTime, right?
But, I'm getting the following error:
*Expected argument of type "?string", "DateTime" given at property path "value".*
Any help would be great!